# VUETIFY V-DATA TABLE, Hide table header, according to a conditional

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

How can I hide and show a vuetify table header? I need to show or hide a header if an object contains a particular service.

```
<v-data-table
        style="position: relative; z-index: 0"
        class="pa-0"
        dense
        disable-pagination
        disable-sort
        fixed-header
        :headers="headers"
        :height="height"
        hide-default-footer
        :items="locations"
        item-key="id"
        :loading="loadingDataTable"
        :ref="'datatable'"
        @click:row="highlightRow"
        @current-items="currentItems"
        calculate-widths
>
<template v-slot:item.headerHidden="{ item }">
          <span class="secondary--text text-lg-caption text-xl-body-2">
            {{ value }}
          </span>
</template>

</v-data-table>
```

```
data() {
return {
headersMap: {
headerHidden: {
          text: 'Hello
          ),
          align: 'center',
          value: 'headerHidden',
          class: 'secondary--text ml-4'
        },
}
}
}
```

And I must hide that header, depending on the existence of services3, if services3 does not exist it is hidden, if not, it is shown, the structure of the object is:

```
obj: {
services: {
services1: {
...
},
services2: {
...
},
services3: {
...
},
}
}
```

I tried with a computed property and I couldn't solve it, also creating a watcher and I couldn't solve it. Thank